# How to test methods with XDocument.Load()

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have got following code:

```
void Foo(string path){
    try{
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load(path);
        Validate(document);
        //Some logic
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        //Some logic
    }
}
void Validate(XDocument document){
     XmlSchemaSet schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
     schema.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("XsdFile")));
     document.Validate(schema, null);
}
```

How to test this method? I would like to check three cases:
- Correct XML
- Incorrect XML
- Not XML (for example .bmp file in path)
I'm using Visual Studio tests.

Comment: This is a bit broad as there are many approaches and also some alternatives to the current design.

Comment: Provide an example closer to the actual problem and lets see if we can improve the design and ultimately the test as well. This can be classified as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I guess there is a problem with static "XDocument.Load()"?
This example is dentical to my code, only different is in "Some logic", but there are just few operations, that does not matter.

Comment: Correct, among a few other things

Comment: @JoeDoe, if you're mocking objects then yes, having static methods can be an issue. What have you tried?

Comment: I was thinking about mocking it somehow, but it is not possible (at least I could not do that). I also thought about use interface/Class which would call static method.

Comment: @JoeDoe Ok I started fixing the short comings of this code and it is growing fast. definite [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). This now leads me to ask, exactly what it is you want to test. Yes you gave scenarios but what exactly you want to test? that exception is caught, or something else in the logic you omitted from the original question

Comment: I must write Unit test for this method for work. I know it is triumph of form over content, but it was not my decision. ;)

Comment: @JoeDoe Then go with the other answer provided that suggested deploying a file for test. have a separate file that satisfies each scenario and you should be good to go. That would just be a band aid on the bad code and will only cause you issues in the future. happy coding and good luck.

Answer (score 2):

This code is tightly coupled to static implementation concerns, and given the title and question asked leads me to believe this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Addressing the shortcomings of this code, it would need to be refactored to decouple it from implementation concerns.

The actual loading and validating of the document can be delegated out to their own concerns as demonstrated in the following example

```
public interface IDocumentLoader<T> where T : class {
    T Load(string path);
}

public interface IXDocumentLoader : IDocumentLoader<XDocument> { }
public class XDocumentLoader : IXDocumentLoader {
    public XDocument Load(string path) {
        return XDocument.Load(path);
    }
}

public interface IDocumentValidator<T> where T : class {
    void Validate(T document);
}

public interface IXDocumentValidator : IDocumentValidator<XDocument> { }
public class XDocumentValidator : IXDocumentValidator {
    public void Validate(XDocument document) {
        XmlSchemaSet schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schema.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader("XsdFile")));
        document.Validate(schema, null);
    }
}

public class Subject {
    private IXDocumentLoader loader;
    private IXDocumentValidator validator;

    public Subject(IXDocumentLoader loader, IXDocumentValidator validator) {
        this.loader = loader;
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    public void Foo(string path) {
        try {
            XDocument document = loader.Load(path);
            validator.Validate(document);
            //Some logic
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //Some logic
        }
    }
}
```

The majority of the provided login in the original example has be delegate out. This would allow each aspect to be tested in isolation without side effects and even the need to load an actual `XDocument` from disk if so desired.

The given scenarios can be tested with only the necessary dependencies provided for that test. This can be used to test that exception is caught, or something else in the logic you omitted from the original question.

Using a SOLID approach when designing code allows it to be easier to maintain, which would include unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy additional files when your test is run using the `[DeploymentItem]` attribute. They will be copied to `TestContext.TestDeploymentDir`.

```
// assume this XML file is in the root of the test project, 
// and "Copy to Output Directory" property of the file is set to "Copy always"
const string ValidXmlFileName = "valid.xml"; 

[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem(ValidXmlFileName)]
public void Validate_ValidXml_ShouldBeOk() {

    string path = Path.Combine(TestContext.TestDeploymentDir, ValidXmlFileName);

    // perform test with the deployed file ...
}
```

Further reading: [How to: Deploy Files for Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx)